# Orika mapper - map to List<String>

Tags: java, mapper, orika

I have one object with the field `List<AnotherObject>` and I want to map it to a second object with field `List<String>`. I need to map 2 objects. I can not find the way.

Situation map class One -> class Two :

```
public class One {
    String field11;
    List<AnotherObject> field12;
}
```

```
public class AnotherObject {
    String field31;
    String field32;
}
```

```
public class Two {
    String field21;
    List<String> field22;
}
```

```
mapperFactory.classMap(One.class, Two.class)
    .fieldAToB("field11", "field21") //ok
    .fieldAToB("field12{field31}", "field22") //KO //because this is String (end element) --- > List<String>
```

The real business is much bigger than the example so I rule out making a custom mapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to map it like this:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(One.class, Two.class)
    .fieldAToB("field11", "field21") //ok
    .fieldAToB("field12{field31}", "field22{}") //ok
```

Notice the empty braces `{}`